# Why am I getting an error in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
 res.send({
          customerDetails:{
            fName,
            lName,
          },
          applicantDetails:{
            [
              {primaryApplicant:{fName1,lName1}},
              {secondaryApplicant:{fName2,lName2}},
              {thirdApplicant:{fName3,lName3}}
            ]
          }
        })
```

I am getting an error saying " ':' expected " when I hover over the 2nd last '}' bracket.
How to send the above response?

Comment: `applicantDetails`  does not have a key

Comment: Remove the 2nd last '}' and the '{' after `applicantDetails:`

Comment: Could you please send the code for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applicantDetails is an array and you are using object.

```js
let fName = "fName", lName = "lName", fName1 = "fName1", lName1 = "lName1", fName2 = "fName2", lName2="lName2", fName3="fName3", lName3="lName3";
var obj = {
          customerDetails:{
            fName,
            lName,
          },
          applicantDetails:
            [
              {primaryApplicant:{fName1,lName1}},
              {secondaryApplicant:{fName2,lName2}},
              {thirdApplicant:{fName3,lName3}}
            ]
          
}
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is wrong, you probably want `applicantDetails` to be an array instead of an object.

```js
const res = {
  customerDetails: {
    fName,
    lName,
  },
  applicantDetails: [{
      primaryApplicant: {
        fName1,
        lName1
      }
    },
    {
      secondaryApplicant: {
        fName2,
        lName2
      }
    },
    {
      thirdApplicant: {
        fName3,
        lName3
      }
    }
  ]
}
```